# Constant writing operations on google cloud database

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have a MySQL 8.0 cluster database and so far I'm using it to test a couple of things, so I only write from time to time. Problem is that I have realised that there are write operations all the time. Even if my apps are not writing to it.

This is a screenshot of the dashboard.

Just to mention, I have another cluster in Digital Ocean and this issue is not happening there.

Any help will be appreciated
[image: example of writing operations]

UPDATE (2021-03-09)
Executing query as Vérace suggested:
[image: query]

As I see that `time_zone_transition` is the one growing the most

Comment: Hi again - I was reviewing the queues and your question came up (voted not to close! :-) ) - but I remarked (which I previously hadn't) that these writes that you have noticed  aren't occurring on a (presumably?) similar cluster.  This strikes me as very puzzling to say the least as I would expect that the "housekeeping" to which I refer in my answer to occur on both - are there any differences in architecture, HW, Digitial Ocean subscription for your two clusters? I presume that you're running Linux (same OS/version)? Your cluster s/ware (which is?) should be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a university course in Data Visualisation, I used the [Prometheus/Grafana](https://prometheus.io/docs/visualization/grafana/) stack  (great s/ware) to present images of various database metrics while running various [HammerDB](https://hammerdb.com/) benchmarks (also an excellent tool).

As part of this, to provide a baseline, I looked at my (single) server "at rest" and noticed (as you have) that there was activity - albeit a very small amount (~ 10 writes/second) - on an "inactive" server.

Basically, this is "house-keeping" functionality which happens even if there is no ongoing external DDL or DML.

There is an interesting article [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/12/17/impact-of-the-number-of-idle-connections-in-mysql/) and [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/12/20/impact-of-the-number-of-idle-connections-in-mysql-version-2/) (more recent and probably more accurate) showing the impact of the number of idle connections on the NOTPM (No. of Transactions Per Minute) results from the [DBT2 benchmark tool](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/benchmarks.html).

As you can see from the results displayed in the second article, there is a small (but **not** non-existent) effect from just having idle connections.

You say that you are running a cluster - I would imagine that there is a  communications overhead there with nodes pinging each other even in the absence of any serious workload (or even any workload at all).

You don't mention what cluster (NDB? Galera?), but I'm sure that a delve into the code (way above my pay grade... :-) ), a search, or a question on your cluster's architecture/guru list would be able to provide more detail.

If you're interested and have the time and the inclination to test what's going on, you may like to leave your "inactive" cluster running for a while (say over a weekend?) and run (some variant of) this query before and after you begin the test (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620198/how-to-get-the-sizes-of-the-tables-of-a-mysql-database)):

```
SELECT 
     table_schema AS the_db, 
     table_name AS the_table, 
     round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `size_in_mb` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

You might like to include the information_schema (and the mysql schema) as well since some/much/all of this activity that you are seeing might be occurring there.

This would presumably be dependent on the architecture of your cluster. Inserting the results of these queries into tables of their own should render any comparisons which you may wish to do relatively trivial.

Also, bear in mind that there may not be a whole lot to see, as these writes may simply be UPDATEs of a single or just a few records?

p.s. welcome to the forum and +1 for an interesting question!

Comment: Wow! Such an interesting and detailed answer! Thanks a lot for your time. I’ll run that query you mention. I was worried because they are write operations and even if the amount is insignificant, every day the space left is less. So 3 days ago was 1,221GB and now is 1,224GB without using it 

Comment: Done! Upvote can't be seen because of my reputation, but it is there :)

Comment: @JuanWilde - thanks - sometimes votes take a while to come through - though, even with very low rep., you should be able to upvote **and** mark as correct your **own** questions! Anyway, we'll see - just glad that my answer was of use to you! :-)

Comment: You could add a list of the tables that are increasing in size to your question to make it more complete - and maybe help to tease out exactly what "housekeeping" might be taking place during periods of "inactivity"!

Comment: You mean with the query you have provided?

Comment: Yes - with that query - compare before and after and maybe give the top 10? Or perhaps those which have become **proportionately** larger - that **might** be more important than actual physical size increase? I'm kinda shooting in the dark here because I don't know what cluster you are running (Galera,  Percona, NDB... whatever...)  - but I would be interested in definitively determining what's going on - as I said, I noticed this issue with a **single** server - so I would imagine that a cluster would have more of this type of activity due to inter-machine comms... keep us posted...

Comment: Done. I added a screenshot and will do the same in a couple of days. I don't have too much expertise on this, so I appreciate your help :)